FCN grid predicts issue. Arelabels and loss is true in FCN deep learning
I am working on FCN. I have initial labels which are set to 1. I implemented tophat filter to get initial labels. I want to train FCN with these labels.
Here is my sample image and label. After 1 epoch results are average but there are lines like grid. I didn't find the problem.
İmages, labels predicts, and codes below.
image
image with label. Black is 1,transpatrent is 0
Test image
Predicts>0.6
And its my code

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X.transpose(0,1,3,4,2),Y.transpose(0,1,3,4,2),test_size=0.2,random_state=42,shuffle=True,stratify=None)

y_train=keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test=keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test)

images_train_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(X_train)
labels_train_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train)

images_test_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(X_test)
labels_test_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_test)


# Create a dataset from tensors
dataset_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images_train_tensor, labels_train_tensor))
dataset_test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images_test_tensor, labels_test_tensor))

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), name='input')

model_VGG16 = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor = inputs)

for layer in model_VGG16.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

pool3 = model_VGG16.get_layer('block3_pool').output
pool4 = model_VGG16.get_layer('block4_pool').output
pool5 = model_VGG16.get_layer('block5_pool').output
pool5.trainable = True

conv_pool_3 = Conv2D(filters=2, kernel_size=1, padding='same', activation=None)(pool3)
conv_pool_4 = Conv2D(filters=2, kernel_size=1, padding='same', activation=None)(pool4)

conv_inter_1 = Conv2D(filters=1024, kernel_size=1, padding='same', activation=None)(pool5)
conv_inter_2 = Conv2D(filters=1024, kernel_size=1, padding='same', activation=None)(conv_inter_1)
conv_pool_5 = Conv2D(filters=2, kernel_size=1, padding='same', activation=None)(conv_inter_2)

up_x2_1 = Conv2DTranspose(filters=2, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(conv_pool_5)
add_1 = add([up_x2_1, conv_pool_4])
up_x2_2 = Conv2DTranspose(filters=2, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(add_1)
add_2 = add([up_x2_2, conv_pool_3])
up_x2_3 = Conv2DTranspose(filters=2, kernel_size=4, strides=8, padding='same', activation='relu')(add_2)
output_layer = Activation('sigmoid')(up_x2_3)

model_fcn_8s = Model(inputs,output_layer)

#model_fcn_8s.summary()

model_fcn_8s.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001, decay=1e-06), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])



early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',patience=2)

epochs = 2
batch_size = 40

history = model_fcn_8s.fit(dataset_train,
                epochs = epochs,                
                validation_data=dataset_test,                
                callbacks=[early_stop]
                )

I want to improve my predicts.
